# Нужно передать много radiobutton из одной формы во вторую, как это лучше сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть много `input type="radio"` в одной форме, `PopUp-ом` открывается вторая, при нажатии `узнать результат`. Нужно передать все выбранные `input type="radio"` во-вторую, чтобы отправить в обратном письме. Как это лучше сделать? Слышал про сериализацию данных формы, но реализовать не получается, если не трудно, приведите пример, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю. Фрагмент кода формы прилагаю:

```html
<form class="need-sect__form" action="#">
  <label class="need-sect__label">Вопрос</label>
  <div class="need-sect__check-container">
    <label class="need-sect__check-block">Да
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes"><span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="need-sect__check-block">Нет
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no" checked><span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <label class="need-sect__label">Вопрос</label>
  <div class="need-sect__check-container">
    <label class="need-sect__check-block">Да
   <input type="radio" name="name2" value="yes"><span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="need-sect__check-block">Нет
   <input type="radio" name="name2" value="no"><span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <label class="need-sect__label">Вопрос</label>
  <div class="need-sect__check-container">
    <label class="need-sect__check-block">Да
   <input type="radio" name="name3" value="yes"><span></span>
    </label>
    <label class="need-sect__check-block">Нет
   <input type="radio" name="name3" value="no"><span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="need-sect__btns">
    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim def-btn" href="#small-dialog">Узнать результат </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `radioButton` нужны для того, чтобы был выбран только 1 из них. Зачем передавать все? Уточните вопрос. Ну и код желательно

Comment: Да, но там не один radioButton, и мне их все нужно одной строкой передать во вторую форму, посредством jquery, всё это дело происходит на одной странице.

Comment: Вы хотите  скопировать `html` из одной формы в другую? Или Вы хотите передать из одной формы в другую выбранные значения?

Comment: Второй вариант, передать из одной в другую (в частности, в input type="hidden" в value ). Чтобы использовать для отправки обратной связи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", getValue)

function getValue(){
var show = document.forms.show;
var hidden = document.forms.hidden;
for (var i=0; i<show.length; i++){
 hidden[i].checked = show[i].checked;
}
}
```

```html
<form name="show">Show
<label><input type="radio" name="r1">Да</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r1">Нет</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r1">Наверное</label>
</form>
<br>
<form name="hidden">Hidden
<label><input type="radio" name="r1">Да</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r1">Нет</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r1">Наверное</label>
</form>
<button id="btn" type="button">Передать значения</button>
```

**UPD:**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", getValue)

function getValue(){
var show = document.forms.show;
var hidden = document.forms.hidden;
for (var i=0; i<show.length; i++){
 if (show[i].checked == true){
  hidden[0].value = show[i].value;
  console.log(hidden[0].value );
 }
}
}
```

```html
<form name="show">Show
<label><input type="radio" name="r1" value="1">Да</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r1" value="2">Нет</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="r1" value="3">Наверное</label>
</form>
<form name="hidden">Hidden
<label><input type="hidden" name="r1"></label>

</form>
<button id="btn" type="button">Передать значения</button>
```

Comment: Так, это сработает только в условиях, если из одного инпута в другой передавать  такого же типа, но не хиддена, а нужно передать все вопросы с классом  
<label class="need-sect__label">Вопрос1</label> 
<label class="need-sect__label">Вопрос2</label>
одной строкой в другую форму в один лишь input

Comment: Так вопросы передавать или `выбранные значения`(ответы)? 
 И что значит "одной строкой" `html`? Соберетесь с мыслями - приходите.

Comment: Добавил   код  .  . .

Comment: Получилось! то что надо.